# I can't git push recently, what happened to my Git?

Tags: git, github, push

Recently, I try to `git push` my recent project to GitHub, but it can't, it blocked like this:

```
$ git push web4 master
Counting objects: 1035, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (645/645), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1035/1035), 49.44 MiB | 16.01 MiB/s, done.
Total 1035 (delta 298), reused 227 (delta 61)
```

And didn't move at all, so I have to cancel. I also tried to use idea VCS, and it didn't work either. It said:

```
Push failed
Failed with error: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200
```

And tried change the remote and post buffer, too. All didn't work. So, what happened on earth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue can be related to git/https buffer settings. The default file post size might be exceeded. Try to run the following command ant then try to push again.

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

If you are posting over ssh instead of http, so use the following:

```
git config ssh.postBuffer 524288000
```

It increases the buffer to ~500MB and may solve the problem.

Comment: i've already tried,and it didn't work,thanks for your comment.

Comment: i even change the buffer to 1G  xD

Answer (score 1):

Addionally, if you're using nginx, change the  client_max_body_size to 0. This will allow you to push data of any size.

```
client_max_body_size 0
```

Comment: sadly,i don't use nginx

Answer (score 0):

it might be a internet error,when i try to git push the other repository not just in github,it succeeded.Maybe there are some reasons of my location.